# Executing PHP script by cronjob - A path to a data directory in /var/www/html/ directory is not being read in the script

Tags: php, cron, filesystems, ubuntu-16.04, fopen

Here is a PHP script:

```
<?php 
$pathToDirectory = "/var/www/html/Tests/Workspace/data";
echo "pathToDirectory: " . $pathToDirectory . "\n";
?>
```

In my Ubuntu 16.04 OS, I am trying to execute this script every minute as a part of a cronjob. I have added the cronjob like so to my `root`'s crontab file:

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/Tests/Workspace/phpScript.php >/var/www/html/Tests/Workspace/logs/cronScriptOutput.out
```

And the cronjob runs successfully. The problem is that once the cronjob has run, following are the contents of the cronScriptOutput.out file.

```
pathToDataDirectory:
```

And that's it. That actual path string is NOT printed.

The question is why? How do I fix this.

This might not seem serious here, but the problem is that I need to read a file from that path and go further from there. So I need this fixed. I need that path to be read in my PHP script.

Comment: There are no errors in your code. Is it all code you have?

Comment: @IvanBolnikh Yes. Can you please try this if you have Linux OS?

Comment: May be you need add `php ` before script name? `* * * * * php /var/www/html/Tests/Workspace/phpScript.php >/var/www/html/Tests/Workspace/logs/cronScriptOutput.out`  Of course, better use full path to php - /usr/bin/php - or what you have

Comment: @IvanBolnikh OHh you are a hero. Adding `php` did it. If you can write that as an answer, I will mark it as accepted, and that will help future visitors as well. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need add php before script name?

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/Tests/Workspace/phpScript.php >/var/www/html/Tests/Workspace/logs/cronScriptOutput.out
```

Of course, better use full path to php - /usr/bin/php - or what you have